# Switching image according to the theme on Github wiki page markdown is not working

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I'm working on the github wiki page updates and uploaded image. And I'd like to switch the image according to the github dark/light mode theme.
But it's not working with `#gh-dark-mode-only` or `#gh-light-mode-only` same as Github readMe markdown.

```
![Termux Logo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72879799/153904003-d7dee710-6552-4d23-a803-7a9a0ba67d92.png#gh-dark-mode-only)
![Termux Logo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72879799/153904095-9d78a019-8495-4035-8174-e3da8e4dd66b.png#gh-light-mode-only)
```